# Can't compile application when including Intercom Android SDK using Hyperloop

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, intercom, hyperloop

I have an Alloy app that I am trying to include Intercom's Latest SDK (3.1.2). I was able to compile the iOS app with no problems. However, when trying to compile the Android version, it throws errors.

Titanium SDK: 6.0.3GA
Hyperloop: 2.0.1
Android Build Tools: 23.0.1

Command that causes error while building:

> Packaging application:
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Library/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt
>   "package" "-f" "-m" "-J"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/android/gen"
>   "-M"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/android/bin/assets"
>   "-S"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/android/res"
>   "-I"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23/android.jar"
>   "-F"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/android/bin/app.ap_"
>   "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages"
>   "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:io.intercom.android.sdk.gcm:io.intercom.android.sdk"
>   "-S"
>   "/var/folders/xh/4kptgxf94q99cc4rrwz1l56r0000gn/T/117231-7807-19ndtdv/res"
>   "-S"
>   "/var/folders/xh/4kptgxf94q99cc4rrwz1l56r0000gn/T/117231-7807-z4fljn/res"
>   "-S"
>   "/var/folders/xh/4kptgxf94q99cc4rrwz1l56r0000gn/T/117231-7807-15jhg3m/res"
>   "-S"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-gcm-3.1.2/res"
>   "-S"
>   "/Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res"

Errors thrown:

> [ERROR] :  Failed to package application: [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:12:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expanded' in
>   package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:20:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scrollFlags'
>   in package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:26:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_collapseMode' in package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :
>   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:33:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_collapseMode' in package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :
>   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:42:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in
>   package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:72:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in
>   package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:89:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in
>   package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:93:
>   error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in
>   package 'com.boatyard.hyperloop' [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:42:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_behavior' with value
>   '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:72:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_behavior' with value
>   '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:89:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_behavior' with value
>   '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_conversation_coordinator.xml:93:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_behavior' with value
>   '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_expander_button.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_marginBottom' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_expander_button.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_marginEnd' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_expander_button.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_marginRight' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_activity_margin'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_expander_button.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value
>   '@drawable/intercom_composer_circular_ripple'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gallery_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_height' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_with_status_bar_height'). [ERROR] : 
>   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gallery_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value
>   '@color/intercom_composer_full_screen_toolbar'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] :
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gallery_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'fitsSystemWindows' with value
>   '@bool/intercom_composer_fits_system_windows'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gallery_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingTop' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_content_offset'). [ERROR] :
>   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gif_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_height' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_with_status_bar_height'). [ERROR] : 
>   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gif_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'background' with value
>   '@color/intercom_composer_full_screen_toolbar'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] :
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gif_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'fitsSystemWindows' with value
>   '@bool/intercom_composer_fits_system_windows'). [ERROR] :   [ERROR] : 
>   /Users/matiaspenela/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/BoatyardHyperloop/build/hyperloop/android/intercom-sdk-base-3.1.2/res/layout/intercom_gif_input_toolbar.xml:1:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingTop' with value
>   '@dimen/intercom_composer_toolbar_content_offset').

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have Hyperloop properly enabled?

Comment: I think I do, on tiapp.xml module section both android and ios platforms are starred for hyperloop. Additionally, iOS compiles and works perfectly, thus I assume Hyperloop is working well. Unless there is a different way I should check or different settings are needed for Android.